# Is "landscape filled with nature" a pleonasm?

Tags: pleonasms

Does the sentences "landscape" and "landscape filled with nature" mean the same thing? In other words, does a landscape always have to have nature in it?

Comment: Downtown New York City is a landscape.

Comment: May depend on whether you're talking in life or art. In life, no. In art, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Landscapes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/landscape) are not restricted to just natural things.  For example, TFD defines *landscape* as:

> An expanse of scenery that can be seen in a single view

In this case, roads, buildings, and other man-made objects could be scenery, and therefore part of the landscape.

However, your confusion may arise because we have a specific word for views of a city: *[cityscape](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cityscape)*.

Of course, there is the [philosophical](http://forums.philosophyforums.com/threads/everything-is-natural-36233.html) [argument](http://www.ted.com/conversations/9594/everything_is_natural.html) that everything is necessarily "natural" because everything that comes from "natural" things are themselves natural.

However, assuming you are going with the fairly common definition of natural, which distinguishes between man-made things and non-man-made things, then "landscape" is not necessarily a "landscape full of nature".

Answer (score 0):

No. What if the landscape is a polluted city? I wouldn't call that filled with Nature :)